# Jquery validation async not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have made this function, that seems to work fine, but it return "#" insted of wainting for the AJAX. I have tried to remove the return call, with out look.

It need to wait until the AJAX is finish before return. The JSP is working fine.

What is wrong?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("knidExist", function(value, element) {
    var valid = "#";
      $.ajax({
          async: false,
          type: "POST",
          url: "USER.jsp",
          data: "knid="+value,
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(msg) {
              // if the user exists, it returns a string "true"
              if($.trim(msg) != "true") {
                 //return false;
                 valid = false;  // already exists
              } else {
                 //return true;
                 valid = true;      // username is free to use
              }
          }  
     });
    return valid;
}, 'This USER does not exist');
```

Comment: The first A in AJAX stands for **Asynchronous**. Trying to make the function return after the call has finished is a very bad idea. You need to re-examine your approach instead.

Comment: I'm thrilled which solution somebody will provide for us !

Comment: @Jon - they have set async: false.  They are trying to do the call synchronously.

Comment: @jfriend00: It still remains a very bad idea. :)

Comment: @Jon - agreed.  Synchronous ajax is evil.  I would never use it myself.  Locks up the browser.  Your answer that allows use of async requests is probably a better way to go.  Still, from a pure intellectual curiosity point of view, it isn't clear to me why what the OP has doesn't work.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space in your URL? If not, then fetching the resource will fail, so the "success" callback will not execute, and the result variable will not be changed from "#".

Comment: @user359996: The space a just a something that jump in when i copy the text. I will edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a method by my self. Almost a complete copy from the remote method but with static message and url.
Hope i can help some one.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("userExist", function(value, element, param) {
if ( this.optional(element) )
    return "dependency-mismatch";

var previous = this.previousValue(element);
if (!this.settings.messages[element.name] )
    this.settings.messages[element.name] = {};
previous.originalMessage = this.settings.messages[element.name].remote;
this.settings.messages[element.name].remote = previous.message;

param = typeof param == "string" && {url:param} || param;

if ( this.pending[element.name] ) {
    return "pending";
}
if ( previous.old === value ) {
    return previous.valid;
}

previous.old = value;
var validator = this;
this.startRequest(element);
var data = {};
data["**user**"] = value;
$.ajax($.extend(true, {
    url: "validation.jsp",
    mode: "abort",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
        validator.settings.messages[element.name].remote = "**This user do not exist"**;
        var valid = response === true;
        if ( valid ) {
            var submitted = validator.formSubmitted;
            validator.prepareElement(element);
            validator.formSubmitted = submitted;
            validator.successList.push(element);
            validator.showErrors();
        } else {
            var errors = {};
            var message = response || validator.defaultMessage( element, "remote" );
            errors[element.name] = previous.message = $.isFunction(message) ? message(value) : message;
            validator.showErrors(errors);
        }
        previous.valid = valid;
        validator.stopRequest(element, valid);
    }
}, param));
return "pending";
}, "");
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of adding your own validation method, you need to use the built-in [`remote`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) validation method instead which is designed exactly for this purpose.

You would use it in a manner like

```
remote: {
    type: "POST", 
    url: "USER.jsp",  
    data: { knid: value },
}
```

Check out the examples the docs link to.

Comment: I know this method, but i am going to use this validation method 100 times, so it will be good to make it as a method as the jquery validation also can do.

Answer (score 0):

Making those request types of "Post" type causes the issue. 
this basically submits the value and did not wait for the response.
-try making it of type "get" it will work.