# Return value from async ajax request to required method of jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) (JVP) to perform server-side validations via ajax. Everything works perfectly fine except one thing: JVP can't perform remote validation of blank fields.

I don't mind to use its default rule `required: true` for attributes with simple presence validation. But sometimes I have complex logic in my models, and I'd like to keep it on the server-side.

So the problem: I can't force JVP to validate blank field via his build-in remote ajax method. But I can use function in his `required` method (which should get true or false as result):

```
required: function(element) {
  return true_or_false;
}
```

So I decided to use async ajax request inside this function, but I can't return the value from async ajax call. I tried use the callback, but can't make it work and I stuck with this problem. Here is my code (CoffeeScript):

```
validate_url = '/emails/validate'

required_validate = (e, callback) ->
  data = {}
  data[e.name] = $(e).val()
  $.ajax(
    url: validate_url
    type: 'post'
    dataType: 'json'
    data: data
    success: (response) ->
      callback(response)
  )

$('#my_form').validate(
  rules:
    'email[email]':
      required: (element) ->
        required_validate(element, (response) ->
          if response == true || response == "true"
            false
          else
            true
        )
)
```

I checked all data, that goes to the server and the response from it — it's ok.
The problem that `required` method of JVP don't wait for response and gets `true` all the time. How can I return him the value from `success` ajax request?

Comment: response is `true`, I checked with breakpoints that `if response == true || response == "true"` is `true` and function return `false`, but it's too late — `required` method already got `true`

Comment: What do you mean by "validate blank fields"?  You want a blank field to be required?  If it's blank, why do you need the server to tell you this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your own asynchronous validation method, try using the `remote` method.

The documentation is [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method).

Also, see this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852501/jquery-validation-async-not-working) about this.

Something along these lines (sorry my CoffeeScript is a tad rusty). You'll probably have to tweek the `data` option a little bit to get it just right, but I think this is the general idea of what you need to do.

```
$('#my_form').validate(
  rules:
    'email[email]':
    remote: 
      url: validate_url,
      type: "post",
      data:
          email: () ->
              $(".email_container").val()
)
```

Comment: `remote` method won't be triggered on a blank fields, but I need to validate them on the server side.

Comment: Why do you need the server to validate if a field is empty? Can you add `required` into the rules as well so it will be validated that it exists client side and then any special business rules can remain on the server to be checked by the `remote` method? 

Making a request to a server only to validate that a field is not empty is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Well, it's more about understanding how to get this value, than validating empty fields))

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are doing the way you are trying to do it. The `required` function only gives you the `element` object. If it supported asynchronous validation, it would also pass in a `callback` object. If there is more to this question than that, then I am completely lost at this point.